# Can I make the email address I have in an Awesome Table Directory a hyper link?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi this is the code I am using to display my directory info. Is there a way to have the part called {{Email Address}} show as a hyperlink in the directory?

```
<div class="aboutcontainer">
<div class="photocontainer">
<img src="{{Picture}}" width="100%">
</div>
<p class="aboutname">
<b>{{First Name}} {{Last Name}}</b>
</p>
<p class="department">{{Department}}</p>
<div class="infocontainer">
<div class="basicinfocontainer">
<b>Infos</b>
<p class="info">
<b>Country</b>: {{Country}} <br>
<b>Department</b>: {{Department}}<br>
<b>Position</b>: {{Position}}<br></p>
</div>
<div class="basicinfocontainer">
<b>Contact</b>
<p class="info">
<b>Email</b>: {{Email Address}}<br>
<b>Phone Number</b>: {{Phone Number}}<br></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a hyperlink by replacing

`<b>Email</b>: {{Email Address}}<br>`

with

`<b>Email</b>: <a href="mailto:{{Email Address}}">{{Email Address}}</a><br>`